# How to handle degenerate cases in Seidel's Triangulation Algorithm?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, triangulation, triangular

I'm trying to implement Seidel's Triangulation Algorithm, and already completed the core logic, which works perfectly for non-degenerated polygon with holes. But I don't know how to preceed to handle more general inputs. Including

- a vertex on a segment (degenerated)
- overlapping segments
- multiple vertices at the same position (same x and same y)
- self-intersection

[This thesis](https://sigbjorn.vik.name/Triangulation.pdf) gives some helpful thoughts, but since the description, especially how to define the position numbers according to the relative locations, is not so clear, I stuck at the implementation. Could someone help me with a detailed description?